# Command line arguments not getting counted

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working my way through "Java: A Beginner's Guide", Sixth Edition and I've encountered an area where I'm typing precisely what the book says, but I'm getting a undesired output.

Here's my class:

```
// Display all command-line information
public class CLDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("There are " + args.length + " command-line arguments");

        System.out.println("They are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.println("arg[" + i + "]: " + args[i]);
    }
}
```

My console output:

```
There are 0 command-line arguments
They are:
```

Desired console output:

```
There are 3 command-line arguments
There are: 
arg[0]: one
arg[1]: two
arg[2]: three
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Any thoughts re: why the number of arguments from my code don't match the book's count of arguments would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

The solution to my issue turned out to be very simple. I had been running the sample projects in Eclipse by pressing the "Run" button without specifying arguments, as I've done for the prior 164 pages of the book without issue. The book instructed me to execute the program from the **command line** as follows:

```
java CLDemo one two three // where one two three are the arguments passed
```

Thank you to those who steered me to the solution.

Comment: you are not providing any arguments to the program

Comment: and what command do you type to start the application? if you run through eclipse, you have to configure the arguments in your run configuration

Comment: I'm pressing the Run button in Eclipse. I'll try compiling/running the file from the command line and see what it does.

Comment: @AdrianB in eclipse use `run configuration` to pass command line args

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are running the program from Eclipse where by default zero arguments got passed.

If you want to pass your arguments, you can do it through `run -- >run configuration --> arguments tab.`

[Guide](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html)

Comment: Thank you! I went off the suggested path a bit and have been doing the exercises in Eclipse, rather than a text editor and the command line. That variance accounts for the issue I encountered. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Seems you directly jumped  to Eclipse. Instead of learning command line :)

Comment: Actually, that more accounts for a lack of knowledge of eclipse. I recommend sticking to command prompt until you understand the basics of what is going on, in this case: how arguments are passed. It would 've helped you understand the IDE can't magically know what arguments you would want to pass.